# Adding a label to a symfony 2 form field

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to modify a piece of code that generates an input field using the Symfony 2 framework. The thing he creates the field with a default label equals to the name id of the field, in this case; "amount".

```
<?php 
//++++++++++ descrizione
echo $view['form'] -> row($form["amount"], array(
    //widget
    "widgetArgs" => array(
        "attr" => array(
            'class' => 'input-small tooltipRight', 
            'id' => "gift_amount"
            ),
            "tooltip"=>"gift.tooltip.amount",
            "translation_domain" =>"brand"


         ),
   "labelArgs" => array(
        "label_attr" => array(
            'class' => 'control-label', 
        )) ,"rowType"=>2
      )
  );
?>
```

How can i edit this to make it show a custom label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `label` properties:

```
<?php 
echo $view['form']->row($form["amount"], array(
    'widgetArgs' => array(
        "attr" => array(
            'class' => 'input-small tooltipRight', 
            'id' => "gift_amount"
            ),
            'tooltip'=>'gift.tooltip.amount',
            'translation_domain' =>'brand'
         ),
     'label'  => 'My ammount',
  ));
```

Comment: This works nice, Thanks!, but can you please show me how to do the same but using the translation service?

Comment: You mean with a call to `$this->get('translator')->trans('My ammount')` instead of `'My ammount'`?

Comment: do you think is possible to add some style to the label? because simple by doing 'label' => '<b>My Label</b>' do not work

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what does it render? I know you can add a CSS class with `'attr' => array('class' => 'my_class')` if that could do it for you.

Comment: It just renders the string with the tags <b>

Comment: Well, then I guess using the class is easier!

Comment: Yes it is, please if you have time take a look of my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507049/limit-the-default-years-range-on-symfony-2-php-form