# Limit the default years range on Symfony 2 php form

Tags: symfony

Im generating a form field using php on Symfony like this:

```
  <?php
  echo $view['form'] -> row($form["validend"], array(
      //widget
        "widgetArgs" => array("attr" => array('id' => "gift_validbegin")), 'label'  => 'Data Fine',
        "widgetArgsDay" => array("attr" => array("class"=>"span1",'validate-type'=>'complete')),
        "widgetArgsMonth" => array("attr" => array("class"=>"span1",'validate-type'=>'complete')),
        "widgetArgsYear" => array("attr" => array("class"=>"cspan1",'validate-type'=>'complete'))));
 ?>
```

This generates the default year range, I wonder how can I set a diffrent range, lets say from the actual year to 5 more.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968141/customizing-date-form-in-symfony-2/9968207#9968207

Comment: already saw, but I dont know how to extrapolated that to my schema

Comment: Where do you define your field to be of `date` type?